# Word “panhandle” translation to Russian

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

Panhandle is a narrow strip of territory projecting from the main territory of one state into another state.
Google translates panhandle as попрошайка, попрошайничать (beggar, beg). Is there a one Russian word for panhandle in a geographical context, as in ["Florida panhandle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_Panhandle) for example.

Comment: Panhandle may be called "полуостров" (peninsula) - but this not a common term for the land borders and it is used somewhat metaphorically.

Comment: "Panhandle is a narrow strip of territory projecting from the main territory of one state into another state." - if it's about smth political and adminstrative, it could be translated as анклав... But анклав usually mean an political "island", not a "peninsula"

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the direct translation for "panhandle" would be "ручка скоровородки" - this is the reason why it is called that way in English in first place. **However we don't have a 100% matching term in Russian**.

If one want to talk of specifically of Florida panhandle, one would just say something like "неполуостровная часть Флориды", or "материковая часть Флориды". Technically, panhandles are [salients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salient_(geography)), that is "elongated protrusions of a geopolitical entities, such as a subnational entity or a sovereign state". This term is translated to Russian as ["выступ"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF) but de-facto it's usage (in this context) is not that wide-spread as usage of panhandle in English.

For instance, "Aляскинский выступ" is nowhere close in usage to Alaska panhandle, "Юго-Восточная Аляска" is way more popular. "Северный выступ Западной Виргинии" (another example mentioned in Wikipedia) sounds very artificial - actually in each individual case the actual Russian term varies. Though I have to admit that I miss a Russian counterpart.

Comment: Ручка сковородки, makes sense for it visually resembles panhandle in a geographical context . “Выступ” is probably the closest Russian word for panhandle, however it is very inaccurate since Russia doesn’t have panhandles, and there are no actual выступов neither in Russia, nor in the USA.

Comment: @OohLaLa it's definitely no accurate and this is exactly what I claim in my answer ) unfortunately it's the closest we have. And actually we have panhandle-like territories in Russia as well -  for instance, northernmost part of North Ossetia. We do have such territories, we don't have a term.

Comment: thank you. Quite interesting, at least for me.

Comment: May be the word “вдающийся» is more accurate. A Stretch of land вдающаяся в другую administrative territory.

Comment: вдающийся  is a participle, not a noun, and it's just not used as a synonym to panhandle.

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be "перешеек" (isthmus).